# What is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and why can it be used to execute file?

Tags: linux, files, libraries

Recently, I have learned a trick that if a file lacks executable permissions, we can run that file by using `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

For example, to restore x permission for

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 59K Mar  1  2017 /bin/chmod
```

we can run

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

I really don't know how it can be done, it's not a regular stuff, kind of mystery.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That’s the dynamic linker; if you run it on its own, it will tell you what it does:

> Usage: `ld.so [OPTION]... EXECUTABLE-FILE [ARGS-FOR-PROGRAM...]`

> You have invoked ‘ld.so’, the helper program for shared library executables.
> This program usually lives in the file `/lib/ld.so`, and special directives
> in executable files using ELF shared libraries tell the system's program
> loader to load the helper program from this file.  This helper program loads
> the shared libraries needed by the program executable, prepares the program
> to run, and runs it.  You may invoke this helper program directly from the
> command line to load and run an ELF executable file; this is like executing
> that file itself, but always uses this helper program from the file you
> specified, instead of the helper program file specified in the executable
> file you run.  This is mostly of use for maintainers to test new versions
> of this helper program; chances are you did not intend to run this program.

The linker is used to run dynamically-linked programs. When you run `chmod`, the kernel effectively runs the equivalent of `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/chmod`, as you did manually; the latter works even if the `chmod` binary isn’t executable because the check for execute permission is done by the `execve()` system call on the file that it is being told to execute and in the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/chmod` shell command line, the path passed by the shell to `execve()` is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, not `/bin/chmod`, and it’s the one that is checked for execute permission, `/bin/chmod` is only passed as an argument to the linker. It's the same thing in `/bin/sh ./some-script` where `./some-script` doesn't need to be executable.

You’ll find much more detail on this in the excellent [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) article.