# rhel + /usr/lib64 + how to restore the folder

Tags: linux, rhel, libraries

we move the folder by mistake as

```
mv /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64_bck
```

now we try to move back as

```
mv /usr/lib64_bck /usr/lib64
```

but we get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/mv: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually specify the dynamic loader and library path:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64_bck /usr/lib64_bck/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/mv /usr/lib64_bck /usr/lib64
```

The way this works is as follows. `mv` can no longer run on its own, because its interpreter, `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, has disappeared (on RHEL 7, `/lib64` is a symlink to `/usr/lib64`); so instead of running `mv` directly, we run the interpreter, asking it to load `mv`:

```
/usr/lib64_bck/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/mv /usr/lib64_bck /usr/lib64
```

This will still fail because the dynamic linker can’t find the required libraries, so we specify the updated path, resulting in the command given at the top.

See also [What is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and why can it be used to execute file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400621/86440)

Comment: I dont have words about how to thank you , you saved a production server , you are the best here

Comment: Stephen Kitt , you are welcome to visit our company , how you know about where I am living ?

Comment: @StephenKitt is it possible someway to copy the folder /usr/lib64 , from other machine , because unde r/usr/lib64 , we have some issues with some python modules

Comment: @yael that sounds like you should ask another question with the details of the issues...

Comment: @yael I can’t remember how I figured out where you are (at least, what country you’re in), perhaps from a timezone?