# Hacking LD_LIBRARY_PATH to use a recent bash from a chroot

Tags: bash, debian, linux-mint, dynamic-linking, ld

I try to get a more up to date version of `bash` from `LinuxMint`.

I have a `chroot` with `Debian Sid` in my box.

What I try to do in a `bash` wrapper script, early in my `PATH`

```
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib /path/to/chroot/bin/bash "$@"
```

But I get:

```
/home/mevatlave/bin/bash: line 3: 1492488 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib /path/to/chroot/bin/bash "$@"
```

From the chroot:

```
% ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff237fc000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f94de839000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f94de658000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f94de9af000)
```

Is it feasible?

**EDIT**:

With

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib /path/to/chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/chroot/bin/bash "$@"
```

I get

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found
```

With

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib /path/to/chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/chroot/bin/bash "$@"
```

I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/chroot/bin/bash "$@"
```

**EDIT**2:

I can run this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=C
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib /path/to/chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/chroot/bin/bash "$@"
```

But when I run `bash --version`, I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

- 

```
root@debian-sid_chroot:/# dpkg -l | grep libc6
ii  libc6:amd64                  2.36-8                    amd64        GNU C 
Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dev:amd64              2.36-8                    amd64        GNU C 
Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
```

Comment: What does `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib ldd /path/to/chroot/bin/bash` show?

Comment: Same segfault error. But if I remove the first dir, I get `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /path/to/chroot/bin/bash)
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd465f4000)
 libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007fae09045000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fae08e1d000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fae091d3000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a workaround that avoid me to compile `bash` and the need to maintain it in the future:

#### from chroot

```
# apt install bash-static
```

#### Then, my upgrade script on `LinuxMint`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if mount | grep -q "/home/sid-chroot"; then
    chroot /home/sid-chroot <<< 'apt-get -yy update; apt-get -yy upgrade'
else
    debian-sid <<< 'apt-get -y update; apt-get -y upgrade'
fi

apt update
apt-get install zsh
apt-get -y upgrade
zsh<<EOF
mv /bin/bash /bin/bash.origin
mv /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bash.origin &>/dev/null
cp -a /home/sid-chroot/bin/bash-static /bin/bash
cp -a /home/sid-chroot/bin/bash-static /usr/bin/bash
EOF
```

Comment: I stopped this solution, because the completion of ssh scp crash my terminal emulator tabs. I cannot compile bash 5.2.1, as far as libso6 is not the expected version 2.36 IIRC

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your main dynamic linker is too old, and you need to use the chroot’s:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/path/to/chroot/lib:/path/to/chroot/lib64:/path/to/chroot/var/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/lib:/path/to/chroot/usr/local/lib /path/to/chroot/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/chroot/bin/bash
```

See [What is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and why can it be used to execute file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400621/86440)

Comment: You added a colon at the end of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which can change the result.

Comment: Added a better version, but still have a core dump

Comment: Do you thins there's a global issue to do that? Is it feasible?